# Which solution is correct: $\lim_{x \to \infty} {\frac{x^2+2x+3}{2x^2+x+5}}^\frac{3x-2}{3x+2}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I was solving this question $\lim_{x \to \infty} {\frac{x^2+2x+3}{2x^2+x+5}}^\frac{3x-2}{3x+2}$.

Now, this is solved using $\lim_{x \to a} [1+f(x)]^\frac{1}{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$.

However, there seem to be two methods of approaching this problem and both yield different answers. In the first approach we multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ outside the limit and by $2$ inside the limit and add and subtract $1$ to get in the form of the formula. After solving we get the value of the limit as $e$. In the second approach we add and subtract $1$ inside the limit thus getting it in this form and then evaluating the limit we get $e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Now, the book prefers the first approach and so I am assuming my second approach is wrong, but I can't find for the life of me where it is wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to do a log trick in the second approach?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by a log trick
essentially i take log of the expression and then raise it to the power of $e$ if that's what you mean
but that's in both the approaches as both are solved using the same formula

Comment: You should check the hypothesis about $\lim_{x \to a} (1+f(x))^\frac{1}{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$. It's not valid in general.

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+2 x+3}{2 x^2+x+5}=\frac12$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x-2}{3x+2}=1$, your limit is equal to $\left(\frac12\right)^1=\frac12$.

Comment: @jjagmath do you happen to know what the condition is for that to be valid?

Comment: @dotmashrc that's applied only in the case of $1$ to the power infinity

Comment: Yes. Can you guess it? The important point is that $\log(1+x)\approx x$ when $x$ is close to $0$.

Comment: @aarbee That's not the only case where the identity can be applied. It would work, for example, for $f(x)=\sin x$, $g(x)= \cos x$, $a=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your second approach should work:
$$\frac{x^2+2x+3}{2x^2+x+5} = 1 + \left(\frac{x^2+2x+3}{2x^2+x+5}-1\right)$$$$ = 1 + \underbrace{\frac{-x^2+x-2}{2x^2+x+5}}_{\stackrel{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}-\frac 12}$$
So, you could not use "your rule with $e$", because it would require this term to tend to zero.
So, you actually get
$$\left( 1 +\frac{-x^2+x-2}{2x^2+x+5}\right)^{\frac{3x-2}{3x+2}}\stackrel{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\left(1-\frac 12\right)^1 = \frac 12$$

Comment: it does work and it is the approach of the book
my approach was the second approach which doesn't work

Comment: @dotmashrc Here we go. The 1-1-method works as well.

Comment: yeah the identity just doesn't work here